# Three buttons are caling same Action Method from a Controller - determine which one invoked method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I am working on small MVC application, and on my View,
there are 3 buttons, and all of them are invoking same Action, here is definition of button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="btnSave" value="tabOne"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Submit changes </button>
```

And there is three of them like that, how can I know which one invoked a method, because they are located on three separated TABS and each tab on submit (save changes) need to redirect to a different View, so that's reason why I need to recognize which button invoked my `[HttpPost] Edit` action method..

This is how looks a method which I'm invoking:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ArticleEditViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
//Rest of some code
//Here I need to determine which button called this method so I can redirect user //to a corresponding view, for example 
    if(button1 invoked me)
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Article");
    }
    else if(button 2 invoked me)
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Article");
    }
}
```

So guys that's pretty much all, I have tab controls, 3 button which are submiting same Action method, and I need to figure out which one invoked a method.

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a `name` attribute to buttons with different values

```
<button type="submit" name="clickedFrom" id="btnSave" value="tabOne" >Tab one</button>
<button type="submit" name="clickedFrom" id="btnSave2" value="tabTwo" >Tab Two</button>
```

and add a parameter to your http post action method with same name

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ArticleEditViewModel model,string clickedFrom)
{
   // to do : Check value of clickedFrom and do something
   // to do : return something
}
```

When the form is submitted, browser will send the value of the clicked button in clickedFrom key in the request body

Comment: should I make this string clickedFrom as nullable parameter, in case someday I need to call it from some another view and I'm not gonna pass anything into a my Edit action method, or it's ok to leave it like that just I might check if(clickedFrom!=null) { //Do something } ?

Comment: and there are types that are not, so in case you call for an example Edit method and you don't provide an value for clickedFrom, situation might be dangerous? :D

Comment: not sure what you mean by situation might be dangerous. But in short, you will check the value of clickedFrom variable and act according to that. if you do not provide a value for input element with name "clickedFrom", It will be null. So your code should handle it (If not null , do this, else do that (your conditional redirection))

Comment: vote up for such a nice help! :) thanks a lot my friend, here I got some other question from before so you might take a look maybe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636246/how-to-invoke-javascript-method-based-on-a-value-of-viewbag/44636302?noredirect=1#comment76260642_44636302

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler you are passed an `event` as a parameter to get specific information related to what happened. The specific property you're looking for is [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

```
// Taken from Event.target MDN, this will hide the caller of the event
$("#btnSave").click(function(event) {
    event.target.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

I used jQuery to bind the event for brevity, the difference between it and vanilla JS is negligent in this example

Answer (score 0):

Unless you pass a parameter through javascript, I don't think it's possible.

why don't you just pass the value attribute "tabOne", "tabTwo" or "tabThree"?